# Google Maps Turn by Turn Voice Navigation

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating this map app that is going to use Google Maps, plus all my other intended upgrades. However, is it possible to get the turn by turn voice navigation? Would I have to purchase a license, or is it available in one of the API's?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're looking to do. There are [android intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en) to launch Google maps in directions mode which are free to use. There's also a [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction) that will get you the routes, but not navigation AFAIK. The Directions API will cost money after the 2.5K/day free quota.